# DialogFragment wont show(); from my TextSelectionMenu

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, fragment

In my custom TextSelectionMenu, the user can choose to use a ColorPicker to style certain part of a text. But the `ColorPickerDialog f3` will not show at all!

I get the following error when I call show(); on the `f3` object:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.m.muddzboy.QuoteCreator.CustomColorPicker.ColorPickerDialogFrag2.show(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at org.m.muddzboy.QuoteCreator.CustomTextSelectionMenu.onCreateActionMode(CustomTextSelectionMenu.java:63)
```

The way I initilize my ColorPickerDialog Fragment and shows it works with other classes so I dont understand why I keep getting `NullPointerExceptions` here

The constructor for this class is used in my MainActivity

```
public class CustomTextSelectionMenu extends AppCompatActivity implements android.view.ActionMode.Callback {

private EditText editText;
private Context context;
private static int selectionStart;
private static int selectionEnd;
private static ColorPickerDialogFrag2 f3;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;


public CustomTextSelectionMenu(EditText editText, Context context, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    this.editText = editText;
    this.context = context;
    this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    f3 = ColorPickerDialogFrag2.newInstance(4, Color.BLUE);
    f3.setStyle(android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.AppTheme);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main2, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onActionItemClicked(android.view.ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {

    selectionStart = editText.getSelectionStart();
    selectionEnd = editText.getSelectionEnd();

    if (selectionStart > selectionEnd) {
        int temp = selectionEnd;
        selectionEnd = selectionStart;
        selectionStart = temp;
    }

    if (selectionEnd > selectionStart) {
        Spannable str = editText.getText();
        boolean exists = false;
        StyleSpan[] styleSpans;

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.textcolor:

               //LINE:63
                f3.show(fragmentManager, "ds");

                break;

      }
   }
 }
```

**ColorPickerDialogFrag2 class:**

```
public class ColorPickerDialogFrag2 extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment {

public interface ColorPickerDialogListener {
    void onPreviewColorChanged(int dialogId, int color); // CHANGE: added new method here.

    void onColorSelected(int dialogId, int color);
}


private int mDialogId = -1;
private ColorPickerView mColorPicker;
private ColorPickerDialogListener mListener;


public static ColorPickerDialogFrag2 newInstance(
        int dialogId, int initialColor) {

    ColorPickerDialogFrag2 frag = new ColorPickerDialogFrag2();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("id", dialogId);
    args.putInt("init_color", initialColor);

    frag.setArguments(args);

    return frag;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDialogId = getArguments().getInt("id");
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    Log.d("TAG", "onAttach!");

    // Check for listener in parent activity
    try {
        mListener = (ColorPickerDialogListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new ClassCastException("Parent activity must implement "
                + "ColorPickerDialogListener to receive result.");
    }

}


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog d = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);


    d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    d.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    return d;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.costum_colorpickerview__dialog_color_picker, container);

    mColorPicker = (ColorPickerView)
            v.findViewById(R.id.custom_colorpickerview__color_picker_view);


    mColorPicker.setOnColorChangedListener(new OnColorChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onColorChanged(int newColor) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onPreviewColorChanged(mDialogId, newColor); // CHANGE: send color through interface to listening activity.
            }
        }
    });


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {

        int initColor = getArguments().getInt("init_color");
        mColorPicker.setColor(initColor, true);
    }


    return v;
}


//Når der trykkes på tilbageknappen på mobilen sættes farven og dialogen forsivnder
@Override
public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
    mListener.onColorSelected(mDialogId, mColorPicker.getColor());
    getDialog().dismiss();
}


@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    try {
        Field field = Fragment.class.getDeclaredField("mChildFragmentManager");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(this, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Please post code for `ColorPickerDialogFrag2` class. Also are you sure you need that constructor for `CustomTextSelectionMenu`? I see that it extends `AppCompatActivity`. It's an unusual way to create an Activity.

Comment: @droid8421 actually I dont know exactly what It should extend. Regarding the constructor, yes I need it to pass the objects that I need to work with. I have updated the question with the ColorPickerDialogFrag2

Comment: Use this `LayoutInflater` method to inflate the fragment: View inflate (XmlPullParser parser, 
                ViewGroup root, 
                boolean attachToRoot)

Comment: `ColorPickerDialogFrag2#onCreate()` are the arguments not null?

Comment: @droid8421 onCreate is not called. I have tried to put Log.d() in it but its not reaching to it. Do you want me to use your inflater in the ColorPickerFragment2 class?

Comment: Yes, use the provided inflater method. Also can you create an exception breakpoint for `NullPointerException` and see where that breakpoint appears? I'm not sure if it's in your fragment class or in the Android api